# Google checkout integration in PHP website

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, google-checkout

Although Google provide the documentation for Google checkout API version using Curl; it's hard to understand. Could someone please give me guidance on how I can implement it on my PHP site or give me any link where I can find the tutorial for the integration except the Google tutorial.

I want to implement it on my website http://www.go4film.com

Comment: at first I could not understand either. have to read more.. I wish there is a simple tutorial like on paypal

Answer (score 2):

Here check this out. it includes php sample projects provided by google.

http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/samples/Google_Checkout_Sample_Code_PHP.html

And here's a tutorial for google checkout integration for php: http://www.macronimous.com/resources/google_checkout_integration_for_php.asp
Hope this helps.

**PK**